A question about sum of sequence with fifth powers
$\sum_{r=1}^{p}(4p+3r)^5$
I'm looking for the coefficient of the highest degree term in the formula obtained when this sum is written in terms of $p$. Is there a practical way to do this?
And also lets say the power is not 5 but an positive integer $a$, would there still be a way to find the coefficient of the highest degree term in terms of $a$ and $p$?
(By the way I found this sum from using Riemann Sum for integrating $x^5$ from 4 to 7)

@Aig According to WolframAlpha it is $\frac{12617}{2}$ and the highest degree terms power is 6

Look at Binomial Theorem

@RaulFernandesHorta Thanks for the reference but as far as I can see only related subtitle for my question in that page is "Multi-binomial theorem" but I am not sure it is useful since it seems pretty brute force approach

The highest degree is easy  (assuming $p>0$): your example sum is the sum of $p$ positive bounded terms so between $p(4p)^5$ and $p(4p+3p)^5$, both of which are clearly $\Theta(p^6)$

We may as well write the summand as $(b p + c r)^a$.  and
expanding the summand in powers of $p$ gives
$$\sum_{r = 1}^p (b p + c r)^a = \sum_{r = 1}^p \sum_{k = 0}^a {a \choose k} (b^k c^{a - k} r^{a - k}) p^k = \sum_{k = 0}^a {a \choose k} b^k c^{a - k} p^k \sum_{r = 1}^p r^{a - k}$$
Faulhaber's formula gives that the inner sum has value $\frac{1}{1 + a - k} p^{1 + a - k} + R_1(p)$, where $R_1(p) \in O(p^{a - k})$. In particular, terms in the remainder cannot contribute to the leading term in $p$ in the original expression. The original expression thus has the value
\begin{multline}\sum_{r = 1}^p (b p + c r)^a
= \sum_{k = 0}^a {a \choose k} b^k c^{a - k} p^k \cdot \frac{1}{1 + a - k} p^{1 + a - k} + R_2(p) \\
= \left(\frac{(b + c)^{1 + a} - b^{1 + a}}{(1 + a) c}\right) p^{1 + a} + R_2(p) ,
\end{multline}
where $R_2(p) \in O(p^a)$. So, the degree in $p$ is $\boxed{1 + a}$, and (for $c \neq 0$) the coefficient of the leading term is
$$\boxed{\frac{(b + c)^{1 + a} - b^{1 + a}}{(1 + a) c}} .$$
For the particular case $a = 5, b = 4, c = 3$ in the question statement, the formula yields degree $6$ and a leading coefficient of $\frac{12617}{2}$.
Remark It really just amounts to using the definition of the function and a rearrangement, but we can give a closed form for the original sum in terms of the Hurwitz zeta function, even for values of $a$ other than positive integers: For appropriate $a \neq -1$, $c \neq 0$, we have
$$\sum_{r = 1}^p (b p + c r)^a = c^a \left[\zeta\left(-a, 1 + \frac{b p}{c}\right) - \zeta\left(-a, p + 1 + \frac{b p}{c}\right)\right] .$$
For $a = -1$, $c \neq 0$, $$\sum_{r = 1}^p (b p + c r)^{-1} = \frac{\psi\left(p + 1 + \frac{b p}{c}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{b p}{c}\right)}{c},$$ where $\psi$ is the digamma function.
